# JavaScript function strange behavior (function calling)

Tags: javascript, function

```js
function parent() {
  console.log("parent");

  function child() {
    console.log("child1")
  }
  return child();

  function child() {
    console.log("child 2")
  }
}
parent();
```

The output is: Parent and child2

why instead of child1, child2 is getting print?

Comment: Function definitions are hoisted. Second one overwrites the first one.

Comment: it’s not “strange behaviour” it’s “well-defined behaviour.” you wrote a “strange” program and confused yourself ^_^

Answer (score 1):

The second `child()` overrides the first one. Because of this `child 2` is printed in console.

If you add another (3rd) `child` method below the 2nd one, that method will run.

```js
function parent() {
  console.log("parent");

  function child() {
    console.log("child1")
  }
  return child();

  function child() {
    console.log("child 2")
  }
  
  function child() {
    console.log("child 3")
  }
}
parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS, if you write function same name prior function. JS will redefine function, using the function after. This is overwriting

Answer (score 0):

`function declarations` are hoisted (moved to the top), before the actual execution of code starts.

So imagine both child1 and child2 functions at top, before execution reaches the return statement.
Something like:

```
function parent() {
  *****function child() {
    console.log("child1")
  }******

  *****function child() {
    console.log("child 2")
  }******

  *********

  console.log("parent");

  return child();

}

parent();
```

And also, there is overwriting of child1 function by child2 function here so child2 is returned.